# libvirt "default" network not adding correct IP address ranges to bridge "virbr0"

Tags: libvirt

I'm running libvirt on ArchLinux using its `default` network with manually created nftables rules.

I noticed that libvirt's DHCP server wasn't assigning IP addresses to VMs:

```
journalctl -u libvirtd

Sep 06 17:46:19 laptop dnsmasq-dhcp[8083]: no address range available for DHCP request via virbr0
```

I did some investigating and found that when I take a look at

```
ip addr
```

The `virbr0` bridge only has the IP range `192.168.100.0/24` assigned to it. It's missing the `192.168.122.0/24` range, which is why libvirt's dnsmasq instance is refusing to assign IPs to VMs.

Now, libvirt automatically reconfigures the `virbr0` bridge when I start/stop a VM, so I always have to manually run

```
sudo ip address add 192.168.122.1/24 dev virbr0 broadcast 192.168.100.255
```

to get networking to work.

Is there a configuration issue on my end, or is there something off with how libvirt is treating the bridge?

I'd like to find a way to continue using as much of libvirt's out-of-the-box networking as possible and not have to manually manage the bridge or its IP ranges.

Comment: What is the libvirt configuration for that virtual network?